# Adding IsNotNull and ViewFields in CAML Query

Tags: caml-query, spquery

Trying to add IsNotNull parameter and ViewFields paramter but throwing an error. Am I inserting incorrectly or missing something to make sure this executes correctly? Seems like View is bring back all of the items in the list and just need the item I was original returning before needing to add these other parameter

```
                       SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
                        myquery.Query =
                        "<View>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                            "<And>" +
                                "<Contains>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Group' />" +
                                    "<Value Type='Text'>City</Value>" +                                  
                                "</Contains>" +
                                "<Eq>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='System' />" +
                                    "<Value Type='Text'>" + Param.var.ToString() + "</Value>" +
                                "</Eq>" +
                                "<And>" +
                                "<IsNotNull>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Email' />" +
                                "</IsNotNull>" + 
                                "</And>" +
                                "<ViewFields>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Email' />" +
                                "</ViewFields>" +
                            "</And>" +
                            "</Where>" +
                        "</View>";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't use ViewFields inside the Where clause in a CAML query. See [Query Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx) and [SPQuery.ViewFields Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields.aspx)

Also, the And around the IsNotNull node is doing nothing. The And needs two child elements to operate correctly.

Comment: gotcha! that did the trick for the ViewFields. I didn't know about the IsNotNull, I tink I can figure that one out shortly. Thanks!